# If we are using Generic views in Django, then the templates must be present within the templates folder in the app in which the views are specified?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am new to Django framework and the instructor what normally does is that he joins the path with the base dir for generic templates like base.html and all ,and for login and signup and app specific templates he creates a dir within the app and populates the html there, he never mentioned how it works and I am confused what method would I follow , can someone explain this in an easy way!!

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on people how they decide to structure their template directories.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the methods are okay. Whichever makes you happy. There's no magic behind the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Templates engines are configured with the TEMPLATES setting. It’s a list of configurations, one for each engine. The default value is empty. The settings.py generated by the `startproject` command defines a more useful value:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

1. **DIRS** defines a list of directories where the engine should look for
   template source files, in search order.
2. **APP_DIRS** tells whether the
   engine should look for templates inside installed applications. Each
   backend defines a conventional name for the subdirectory inside
   applications where its templates should be stored.
   It doesn't depend how you define the views .... So For example ...
   Lets see these line of codes ..

## Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Here you can create templates dir in Project dir and templates dir in apps dir as well and django will look for both and renders the files from both dirs ...
For More Look Here in Django Docs [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines)